# How do I get my material-ui cards to lineup horizontally in row direction?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get these material-ui cards to go in a row direction with my grid - I have used these before and had no issues making them lineup in a row direction rather than in a column direction and my code is the same as I used before.

Please let me know what mistakes I have made or solutions you know of!

Just a side note the direction, wrap, justify and alignitems properties I added to the grid have made no difference at all.

Hero.js

```
import { Grid, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import React from 'react'
import MediaCard from './Card'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
  }));

function Hero() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className="Hero">
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Grid  
                    Container spacing={2} 
                    className="hero-section"
                    direction="row"
                    wrap="nowrap"
                    justify="center"
                    alignItems="center"
                >
                    <Grid  item 
                        xs={6}
                        direction="row"
                        justify="flex-start"
                        alignItems="flex-start"
                    >
                        <MediaCard className="hero-card" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid  item 
                        xs={6}
                        direction="row"
                        justify="flex-start"
                        alignItems="flex-start"
                    >
                        <MediaCard className="hero-card" />
                       
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

Comment: Try `<Grid  Container spacing={2} ` `Container` with small letter `container`

Comment: Wow typo got me it always is the simplest mistake, thanks Prabhat!